# Undefined index: action plugin problem

Tags: plugins, functions

i have 4 error in the **plugin logo slider**

the first error in line 89
and i fixed it and one of the other the errors in 225

> Notice: Undefined index: action in
>   /plugins/logo-slider/logo-slider.php on line 89 and the other 3 errors
>   in on line 225

but there is 2 other left in 225

```
225    if(isset($wp_logo_slider_images['update']) == 'Added' || $wp_logo_slider_images['update'] == 'Deleted' || $wp_logo_slider_images['update'] == 'Updated') {
```

and when i click update it give me

> Notice: clean_url is deprecated since version 3.0! Use esc_url()
>   instead. in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 2841

but when i one funcution.php i cant find clean_url so i could replace it

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question to have an actual question? This is not a bug reporting forum.

Answer (score 2):

The logic on line 225 is bad.

```
if(
  isset($wp_logo_slider_images['update']) == 'Added' 
  || $wp_logo_slider_images['update'] == 'Deleted' 
  || $wp_logo_slider_images['update'] == 'Updated') {
```

`isset($wp_logo_slider_images['update'])` is never going to equal 'Added' but that isn't where the error comes in. PHP will try to use `$wp_logo_slider_images['update']` twice on that line without checking that the value is set.

What you need is:

```
if(
  isset($wp_logo_slider_images['update']) 
  && ( 
    $wp_logo_slider_images['update']== 'Added' 
    || $wp_logo_slider_images['update'] == 'Deleted' 
    || $wp_logo_slider_images['update'] == 'Updated'
  )
) {
```

Notice the extra set of `()` to group the `||`s and make sure that PHP does not try to access `$wp_logo_slider_images['update']` if it isn't set.